# Footnotes missing from slides

Tags: beamer, uncover

I am having this weird in latex Beamer class with the `onslide` command. The foot note and page numbers disappear from the first slide: but I can't figure out why.

[image]

The footer is supposed to be the name of the section and the page number. Here is the code that reproduces it

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, 10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{cancel}

%%%%%% THE FOLLOWING CONTAINS THE STYLE DEFINITIONS %%%%%%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\definecolor{gris}{rgb}{0.92,0.92,0.92}
\definecolor{blau-upc}{rgb}{0.07,0.18,0.29}

\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{fg=blau-upc}
\setbeamercolor{capcalera}{bg=blau-upc,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=blau-upc}
\setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[circle]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]
\setbeamercolor{item}{fg=blau-upc}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=false]
\setbeamercolor*{block body}{bg=gris}
\setbeamerfont{block body}{size=\footnotesize}
\setbeamercolor*{block title}{parent=structure,bg=blau-upc,fg=white}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=12mm,text margin right=12mm}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{infolines theme}
{
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=9.5mm,right]{white}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
    \hbox{
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.1\paperwidth,ht=10mm,left]{}
        \end{beamercolorbox}
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.8\paperwidth,ht=3ex,center]{}
            \hspace*{4ex} \footnotesize \insertsection\vskip 4ex
        \end{beamercolorbox}
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.1\paperwidth,ht=3ex,right]{}
            \insertframenumber\hspace*{6ex}\vskip 4ex
        \end{beamercolorbox}
    }
}

\setbeamertemplate{title page}
{
    \vbox{}
    \vfill
    \begin{centering}
        {\usebeamerfont{title}\usebeamercolor[fg]{title}\inserttitle}
        \vskip0.2em
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle}
        \vskip2em\par
        \small\insertauthor\par
        \vskip0.7em\par
        \tiny\insertdate\vskip1em\par
    \end{centering}
}
%%%%%%

%%%%%% TITLE, AUTHOR, DATE DEFINITIONS %%%%%%
\title{Title}

\author{Author}
\date{\today}
%%%%%%
\setbeamercovered{invisible}

\begin{document}

\section{Lemma}
\frame{\frametitle{Proof:}
    \onslide<1->{We had:
        \[Av=\left( -{{e}^{-i\theta }}\left| x \right|\left| y \right|\cos \theta +\left| x \right|\left| y \right| \right)\frac{x}{\left| x \right|}+\left( {{e}^{-i\theta }}\left| y \right|\left| x \right|-\left| y \right|\left| x \right|\cos \theta  \right)\frac{y}{\left| y \right|}\] }
    \onslide<2->{For the second term:
        \begin{align*}
        \left( {\color{red}{e}^{-i\theta }}\left| y \right|\left| x \right|-\left| y \right|\left| x \right|\cos \theta  \right)\frac{y}{\left| y \right|}} \onslide<3->{&={\color{red} \left( \cos \theta -i\sin \theta  \right)}\left| y \right|\left| x \right|-\left| y \right|\left| x \right|\cos \theta  \\ }
    \onslide<4->{& =\cancel{\cos \theta \left| y \right|\left| x \right|}-i\sin \theta \left| x \right|\left| y \right|- \cancel{\left| y \right|\left| x \right|\cos \theta} \\}
    \end{align*}
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`align` and `\onslide` had been nested incorrectly:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, 10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{cancel}

%%%%%% THE FOLLOWING CONTAINS THE STYLE DEFINITIONS %%%%%%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\definecolor{gris}{rgb}{0.92,0.92,0.92}
\definecolor{blau-upc}{rgb}{0.07,0.18,0.29}

\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{fg=blau-upc}
\setbeamercolor{capcalera}{bg=blau-upc,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=blau-upc}
\setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[circle]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]
\setbeamercolor{item}{fg=blau-upc}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=false]
\setbeamercolor*{block body}{bg=gris}
\setbeamerfont{block body}{size=\footnotesize}
\setbeamercolor*{block title}{parent=structure,bg=blau-upc,fg=white}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=12mm,text margin right=12mm}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{infolines theme}
{
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=9.5mm,right]{white}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
    \hbox{
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.1\paperwidth,ht=10mm,left]{}
        \end{beamercolorbox}
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.8\paperwidth,ht=3ex,center]{}
            \hspace*{4ex} \footnotesize \insertsection\vskip 4ex
        \end{beamercolorbox}
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.1\paperwidth,ht=3ex,right]{}
            \insertframenumber\hspace*{6ex}\vskip 4ex
        \end{beamercolorbox}
    }
}

\setbeamertemplate{title page}
{
    \vbox{}
    \vfill
    \begin{centering}
        {\usebeamerfont{title}\usebeamercolor[fg]{title}\inserttitle}
        \vskip0.2em
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle}
        \vskip2em\par
        \small\insertauthor\par
        \vskip0.7em\par
        \tiny\insertdate\vskip1em\par
    \end{centering}
}
%%%%%%

%%%%%% TITLE, AUTHOR, DATE DEFINITIONS %%%%%%
\title{Title}

\author{Author}
\date{\today}
%%%%%%
\setbeamercovered{invisible}

\begin{document}

\section{Lemma}
\frame{\frametitle{Proof:}
    \onslide<1->{We had:
        \[Av=\left( -{{e}^{-i\theta }}\left| x \right|\left| y \right|\cos \theta +\left| x \right|\left| y \right| \right)\frac{x}{\left| x \right|}+\left( {{e}^{-i\theta }}\left| y \right|\left| x \right|-\left| y \right|\left| x \right|\cos \theta  \right)\frac{y}{\left| y \right|}\] }
    \onslide<2->{For the second term:}
        \begin{align*}
      \onslide<2->{  \left( {\color{red}{e}^{-i\theta }}\left| y \right|\left| x \right|-\left| y \right|\left| x \right|\cos \theta  \right)\frac{y}{\left| y \right|}} \onslide<3->{&={\color{red} \left( \cos \theta -i\sin \theta  \right)}\left| y \right|\left| x \right|-\left| y \right|\left| x \right|\cos \theta  \\ }
    \onslide<4->{& =\cancel{\cos \theta \left| y \right|\left| x \right|}-i\sin \theta \left| x \right|\left| y \right|- \cancel{\left| y \right|\left| x \right|\cos \theta} \\}
    \end{align*}
}
\end{document}
```